# Database only saves last iteration , laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

please why is the code below only saves last iteration ？

```
foreach($videos as $video)
    {
       $filename=$video->getClientOriginalName();
        $vidWay=public_path('videos');
        $lessons->video=$filename;
       // echo $filename;
        $video->move($vidWay,$filename);
        $lessons->title=$lesson_titles[$upload_count];
        $lessons->course_id=$Course->id;
        $lessons->save();
        $upload_count++;
            // echo $filename;
    }
```

Any idea ？

Comment: You have to create a new Lessons object each time it iterates, or it will override the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think code must be something like this

```
foreach($videos as $video)
    {
       $lessons=new App\Lessons()
       $filename=$video->getClientOriginalName();
        $vidWay=public_path('videos');
        $lessons->video=$filename;
       // echo $filename;
        $video->move($vidWay,$filename);
        $lessons->title=$lesson_titles[$upload_count];
        $lessons->course_id=$Course->id;
        $lessons->save();
        $upload_count++;
            // echo $filename;
    }
```

Comment: `$lessons=new Lessons();` is written in previous lines

Comment: You must write it inside foreach, to create lessons object in every iteration, or your code will save only last record

Comment: yes !!! thanks  it works now , i didn't know i had to call the table at each iteration

Comment: you're welcome ;) if you want to save for example 6 Lessons you must have 6 different Lessons objects, in your case your'e having 1 Lessons object and updating it 6 times